# Using how in a list of points

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality-in-context

How should I structure the clauses of the list of point in such a sentence:

A system requires at least two kinds of information: i) how is A related to B; ii) how is C related to D.

For example, is the above form correct? or should I use them like

i) how A is related to B; ii) how C is related to D.

Or any other form?

Comment: 1) How ***does*** A relate to B 2) How ***does*** C relate to D. There is no need to use a passive: How is A related to B.

Comment: Or just *how A relates to B*, or *the relationship between A and B*.

Comment: How does A relate to B?=A question. How A relates to B = A statement. Both are fine. I have no idea what you mean by a nuance. The passive version does not denote a who-question. There is no pronoun who here at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your sentence to expand into this one:

> A system needs to know how A is related to B and how C is related to D.

you want:

> 1. A system requires at least two kinds of information: i) how A is related to B, ii) how C is related to D.

Otherwise, you can say:

> 2. A system requires at least two kinds of information which we can obtain by asking the following questions: i) How is A related to B? ii) How is C related to D?

Comment: A system needs to know how A relates to B. There is no need for a  passive here.

Comment: @Lambie What's the difference, anyway? That seems like a random stylistic preference.

Comment: @user2684291 21 No, it is not random. The "rules" of "good writing" call for not using passive unless it is necessary. In this example, it is not necessary. [an easier user name would be easier to respond to]

Comment: @Lam You don't have to use my username as this is my answer (I get pinged automatically), and you don't have to use the entire username elsewhere, only the first 3 characters (and if there are more *user*s, then you'll notice that my username contains an extra r, so you can write just `@userr`). Anyway, yeah, feel free to adhere to the "rules" of "good writing". As I said – it sounds quite arbitrary to me, so I'll leave it like this. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

The correct pattern for the interrogative sentence is **How (in what way) + verb + A + relate to + B**

- How is smoking related to asthma?
- How does a tone relate to a frequency?
- How do we relate to our children?
- How are magnetic fields related to sunspots?

And more:

- In what way are focus, scope and interconnection dimensions related to the higher value creation potential?
- In what way is the SFI related to the Investigator's sponsored project?

However, if you are writing it in a declarative sentence then in the pattern the the verb comes after the A - **How (in what way) + A + verb + relate to + B**

- In this section we will be talking about the basics of acids and bases and how acid-base chemistry is related to chemical equilibrium.
- Instead, we're asking them to make a judgment about how the statement is related to the construct of interest.
- Only recently have scientists begun to understand the alternating cycle of sleep and waking, and how it is related to daylight and darkness.

Comment: If you perceive it carefully, it doesn't look like an interrogative question, which requires the inversion.

Comment: So the question is in my scenario is it a declarative sentence or not?

Comment: @Shayan It much depends on you.